# Приветствие после авторизации пользователя

Tags: jquery, авторизация

скажите как правильно написать код авторизации, у меня сейчас так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            var a_log = $("#a_login").val();
            var a_pass = $("#a_password").val();
            $.post("auth.php",{a_login:a_log,a_password:a_pass}, function(data){
                $("#alert").html(data);
            });

        });
    });
```

то есть если не правильная пара логин/пароль, то выводится "Неверные логин или пароль", а как сделать, чтобы при успешной авторизации форма авторизации убиралась а появлялись например какое нибудь приветствие. Я только начал изучать jQuery вот и не могу придумать конструкцию

Comment: @sew810i9, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery, а тем более Ajax - не относиться к процессу авторизации. Ajax - это способ передачи данных и не более того. Какой язык программирования используете на стороне сервера, на том и нужно искать решения данной задачи. Если вас интересует та часть, которая выполняется на клиенте, то в ответе на ajax-запрос, вы возврашаете true/false, в зависимости от успеха прохождения авторизации.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#btn").click(function(){ 
        var a_log = $("#a_login").val(); 
        var a_pass = $("#a_password").val(); 
        $.post("auth.php",{a_login:a_log,a_password:a_pass}, function(data){ 
            if(data) {
                $("#alert").html('Welcome!'); 
            } else {
                $("#alert").html('Error!'); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: благодарю, уже что то. А что бы форму входа убрать без перезагрузки всей страницы - это можно сделать? Например поместить форму в <div> и его перезагружать с помощью remove(). У меня сейчас так http://pastebin.com/beGxPZAu пока страницу не обновлю не выводится имя пользователя вместо формы